# How is Hadoop-3.0.0 's compatibility with older versions of Hive, Pig, Sqoop and Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-pig, sqoop

We are currently using `hadoop-2.8.0` on a 10 node cluster and are planning to upgrade to latest `hadoop-3.0.0`.

I want to know whether there will be any issue if we use `hadoop-3.0.0` with an older version of Spark and other components such as Hive, Pig and Sqoop.

Comment: The latest Spark 2.2.1 does not support Hadoop 3.0.0.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski , what type of exception it throws?? . i've read on `spark`'s download page that it is for `hadoop` version 2.7 and later. isn't it difficult to digest that latest versions of `spark` and `hadoop` are not compatible with each other.!

Comment: I don't know the specifics unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Hive version does not support Hadoop3.0.It seems that Hive may be established on Spark or other calculating engines in the future.

Comment: yes and performace wise, hive is much more faster when run on spark than hadoop.