# Jar conflicts between apache spark and hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I try to setup and run a Spark cluster running on top of YARN and using HDFS.

I first set up Hadoop for HDFS using hadoop-3.1.0.
Then I configured YARN and started both.
I was able to upload data to the HDFS and yarn also seems to work fine.

Then I installed spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop on my master only and tried to submit an application.
Since it is spark without Hadoop I had to modify spark-env.sh, adding the following line like mentioned in the documentation:

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop classpath)
```

Using only this line I got the following exception:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster
```

Which I guess means that he does not find the Spark-libraries. So I added the spark jars to the classpath:

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop classpath):/usr/local/spark/jars/*
```

But now I get the following Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.8
```

As it turns out, Hadoop 3.1.0 provides Jackson 2.7.8 while Spark 2.3.0 provides Jackson 2.6.7. As I see it, both are now in the classpath resulting in a conflict.

Since it seems I really need both the Hadoop and Spark libraries to submit anything, I do not know how to get around that problem.

Comment: Put Spark libraries before Hadoop classpath... Also, Spark doesn't officially support Hadoop 3.x yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How is Hadoop-3.0.0 's compatibility with older versions of Hive, Pig, Sqoop and Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920005/how-is-hadoop-3-0-0-s-compatibility-with-older-versions-of-hive-pig-sqoop-and)

there was answer from @JacekLaskowski that spark is not supported on hadoop 3. As far as I know, nothing changed for last 6 month in that area.

Comment: I am downgrading Hadoop. Right now I have some problems (namenode doesn't start) but I will report back once I have tried it out.

Comment: I have tested with Hadoop 2.9. Everything works fine now.